# Having problem to fetch/save settings.bundle value by code 

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm facing difficulty in fetching/saving setting bundle preference file by code. I'm a beginner.
I just need to fetch/save default value of key "VERSION 2" by code. I want to use the value of this key for my controllers to work. Thanks.

This data is in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">;
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>DefaultValue</key> 
          <string>Karachi</string> 
        <key>Key</key>
          <string>version2</string> 
        <key>Title</key>
          <string>VERSION</string> 
        <key>Type</key>
          <string>PSTitleValueSpecifier</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>DefaultValue</key>
 <string>Karachi</string>
 <key>Key</key>
 <string>version2</string>
 <key>Title</key>
 <string>VERSION</string>
 <key>Type</key>
 <string>PSTitleValueSpecifier</string>
</dict>
</plist>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do that by simply doing the following

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs - [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; //considering it's in the default settings.bundle
NSString *versionString = [prefs stringForKey:@"Key"];
```

You can use the following methods to get defaults

- arrayForKey
- boolForKey
- dataForKey
- dictionaryForKey
- floatForKey
- integerForKey
- objectForKey
- stringArrayForKey
- stringForKey
- doubleForKey
- URLForKey